# Parsing Json string through command line

Tags: php, json

I'm new to php and Json and i'm trying to decode the command line Json strings , but the Json decode function gives null while decoding , i'm sending the data in the correct format not sure why it is going wrong .I have checked with the threads and the passing the data as per the url `http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php` .

Here is my code

```
<? php

if($argc==2)
{
    $jsonin=$argv[1];

    echo $jsonin."\xA";

    $jsonin="'".$jsonin."'";

    echo $jsonin ."\xA";

    $cmdval=json_decode($jsonin);


    if($cmdval)
    {
       echo $cmdval->{'id'};
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Bad string" ; 
    }



}
else
{
   echo "No arguments";
}


?>
```

This is how i'm passing it to the code

```
php5 jsonparse.php '{ "time1":"2014/10/30 21:30:00", "time2":"2014/10/31 21:30:00" }'
```

following are the outputs

```
 {  "time1":"2014/10/30 21:30:00", "time2":"2014/10/31 21:30:00"}

'{ "time1":"2014/10/30 21:30:00", "time2":"2014/10/31 21:30:00"}'

Bad string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it works like a charm :

```
if($argc==2)
{
    $jsonin=$argv[1];
    $cmdval=json_decode($jsonin);
    if($cmdval)
    {
        echo "You did it right !\r\n";
        print_r($cmdval);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Bad string" ; 
    }
}
else
{
   echo "No arguments";
}
```

And i ran it as below:

```
php test.php '{ "time1":"2014/10/30 21:30:00", "time2":"2014/10/31 21:30:00" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are doing this? `$jsonin="'".$jsonin."'";`
Please remove this code and try again.